# How to detect destroyed blocks in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Ok so I want to make a minigame map. One of the minigames is destroy spawners. So i'm wondering if i can make a system that detects destroyed blocks (in this case: spawners) to test if a player win or not.

Comment: I just checked in 1.8.8 and the latest snapshot (15w42a); It doesn't seem to be possible, as there is no statistic for counting mined spawners.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it by doing

```
/testforblock x y z mob_spawner
```

You could change x y z to the location of the spawner, it will output redstone if it is there. Then make it detect it if the redstone gets unpowered.

You could also just do

```
/testforblock x y z air
```

Which would detect if it's air. So you could detect it if it outputs redstone
(use a comparator).

Comment: ths dude! Just what would work (i'll try it when i get to play)

Answer (score 0):

If the spawners are in set locations, then yes.  You can constantly check if the spawner is broken.  If you want to detect who broke it, then probably not.

Comment: I only need to detect destroyed spawners, but i don't know how. With testfor? help pls

Comment: `/testforblock x y z mob_spawner` ?

Comment: Ths dude. It would work right!